# Holder space in Partial Diferential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u^{\epsilon}\in C^3(\Omega\times(0,T))$, $\tau>0$, $\beta\in(0,1)$ and  $\Omega'\subset\subset\Omega$. Suppose there is a constant $C$ such that:
$$
|u^{\epsilon}(x,t)-u^{\epsilon}(x,s)|\leq C|t-s|^{\frac{1}{1+\beta}}\ ,\ \forall x\in\Omega' , \forall t,s\in(\tau,T)
$$
and
$$
|\nabla u^{\epsilon}(x,t)-\nabla u^{\epsilon}(y,t)|\leq C|x-y|^{\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}}\ ,\ \forall x,y\in\Omega' , \forall t\in(\tau,T).
$$
where $C$ does not depend on $\epsilon$.

Show that there exists the limit  $\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}u^{\epsilon}=u$ and that $u\in C^{\frac{1}{1+\beta}}$ and $u\in C^{1,\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}}$.

PS. I believe we must use compact immersion but found results to solve.

Comment: Try to use Arzelà–Ascoli theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem). At a moment I don't see how to get a uniform boundedness, but probably you can archive it from compactness of inclusion $\Omega' \subset\subset \Omega$.